# how to show decoded password on user details page?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I created a page with users details. Where I can see all the details of users, able to change them if needed. I want to create and check the password for users, and in case when user forgot his password, to provide it. BUT!
I can see only hashed password. the password encoded by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

[image: encoded password]

is there any method for be able to decode this password and to display normal password

[image: decoded password]

I tried to find the answer in internet, but seams that I put the wrong request....

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it is not possible as hashing is a one-way process of transforming input to the fixed-length output.

I suggest rather introducing a password reset mechanism over revealing the password, which is not possible if you use a one-way hashing algorithm.

---

There are, however, legit use cases a secure piece of information can be revealed to the customer/user, for example, the credit/debit card PIN can be displayed on request in most mobile or internet banking applications.

In such a case, the information (card PIN) has to be encrypted by a 2-way algorithm so you don't lose its raw version. I recommend generating a unique key and using salt for each user. I also recommend using another security layer such as OTP challenge.

Comment: thanks for feedback! I will try to display by another way. Regards!